# Multiple Selects to update tblItems - INNER JOIN required?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update the buyersAccountID in tblITEMS with the accountID of a winner who's boxNo in tblEntrants matches 'winner' in tblItems:

```
TBLENTRANTS
fileID
boxNo
accountID

TBLITEMS
fileID
buyersAccountID
winner
```

So to clarify: If 'winner' which is an integer in tblItems matches the integer boxNo in tblEntrants then I need to store tblEntrants.accountID in tblItems.buyersAccountID

fileID also needs to be matched in each table.

```
UPDATE tblItems SET buyersAccountID = SELECT tblEntrants.accountID WHERE tblEntrants.boxNo = tblItems.winner) WHERE fileID=@fileID
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results i.e. a [mre]

Comment: And maybe consider investing the time to run through a few SQL tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With so little information, this may the script you need:

```
UPDATE I
SET I.buyersAccountID = E.accountID
FROM tblItems AS I
INNER JOIN tblEntrants AS E ON I.fileID = E.fileID
AND I.winner = E.boxNo;
```

You can add your `where` after this query (before the semicolon). For example

```
UPDATE I
SET I.buyersAccountID = E.accountID
FROM tblItems AS I
INNER JOIN tblEntrants AS E ON I.fileID = E.fileID AND I.winner = E.boxNo
WHERE I.fileID=@fileID;
```

Comment: That works perfectly thank you. I've done inner joins before but couldn't figure this one out for some reason. Many thanks, it makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have offered little other information, all I can give you is a pattern that should work for you:

```
UPDATE TBLITEMS SET
    buyersAccountID = TBLENTRANTS.accountID
FROM TBLENTRANTS
INNER JOIN TBLITEMS ON TBLENTRANTS.boxNo = TBLITEMS.winner 
AND TBLENTRANTS.fileID = TBLITEMS.fileID
```

I'll leave it to you to try it out, and suggest you also try and understand how it works.

Part of me is thinking that it'll update every record in **TBLITEMS** to have the *buyersAccountID* from the winner, although the inner join should be limiting the result to just the ones that match the *boxNo* and *fileID*. In any case, use the above with caution.

Comment: @DaleK. You were too quick. I was editing the answer, but I disagree with not offering an answer that may help. Even with the limited information they supplied, I can see the general idea of what they are trying to do.